# Passing parameters to the predict function in mlr for xgboost

Tags: r, xgboost, mlr

The latest version of xgboost (0.7) allows for the interpretation of predictions by setting the *predcontrib* parameter to TRUE. I tried to modify the default xgboost learner in order to get these contributions along with the predictions. Here the code (my single addition between START and END):

```
#' @export
makeRLearner.classif.xgboost.c = function() {
  makeRLearnerClassif(
    cl = "classif.xgboost.c",
    package = "xgboost",
    par.set = makeParamSet(
      # we pass all of what goes in 'params' directly to ... of xgboost
      # makeUntypedLearnerParam(id = "params", default = list()),
      makeDiscreteLearnerParam(id = "booster", default = "gbtree", values = c("gbtree", "gblinear", "dart")),
      makeUntypedLearnerParam(id = "watchlist", default = NULL, tunable = FALSE),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "eta", default = 0.3, lower = 0, upper = 1),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "gamma", default = 0, lower = 0),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "max_depth", default = 6L, lower = 1L),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "min_child_weight", default = 1, lower = 0),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "subsample", default = 1, lower = 0, upper = 1),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "colsample_bytree", default = 1, lower = 0, upper = 1),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "colsample_bylevel", default = 1, lower = 0, upper = 1),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "num_parallel_tree", default = 1L, lower = 1L),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "lambda", default = 1, lower = 0),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "lambda_bias", default = 0, lower = 0),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "alpha", default = 0, lower = 0),
      makeUntypedLearnerParam(id = "objective", default = "binary:logistic", tunable = FALSE),
      makeUntypedLearnerParam(id = "eval_metric", default = "error", tunable = FALSE),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "base_score", default = 0.5, tunable = FALSE),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "max_delta_step", lower = 0, default = 0),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "missing", default = NULL, tunable = FALSE, when = "both",
                              special.vals = list(NA, NA_real_, NULL)),
      makeIntegerVectorLearnerParam(id = "monotone_constraints", default = 0, lower = -1, upper = 1),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "tweedie_variance_power", lower = 1, upper = 2, default = 1.5, requires = quote(objective == "reg:tweedie")),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "nthread", lower = 1L, tunable = FALSE),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "nrounds", default = 1L, lower = 1L),
      # FIXME nrounds seems to have no default in xgboost(), if it has 1, par.vals is redundant
      makeUntypedLearnerParam(id = "feval", default = NULL, tunable = FALSE),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "verbose", default = 1L, lower = 0L, upper = 2L, tunable = FALSE),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "print_every_n", default = 1L, lower = 1L, tunable = FALSE,
                              requires = quote(verbose == 1L)),
      makeIntegerLearnerParam(id = "early_stopping_rounds", default = NULL, lower = 1L, special.vals = list(NULL), tunable = FALSE),
      makeLogicalLearnerParam(id = "maximize", default = NULL, special.vals = list(NULL), tunable = FALSE),
      makeDiscreteLearnerParam(id = "sample_type", default = "uniform", values = c("uniform", "weighted"), requires = quote(booster == "dart")),
      makeDiscreteLearnerParam(id = "normalize_type", default = "tree", values = c("tree", "forest"), requires = quote(booster == "dart")),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "rate_drop", default = 0, lower = 0, upper = 1, requires = quote(booster == "dart")),
      makeNumericLearnerParam(id = "skip_drop", default = 0, lower = 0, upper = 1, requires = quote(booster == "dart")),

      ########## START ##########
      makeLogicalLearnerParam(id = "predcontrib", default = FALSE, tunable = FALSE),
      makeLogicalLearnerParam(id = "approxcontrib", default = FALSE, tunable = FALSE),
      ########### END ##########
      makeUntypedLearnerParam(id = "callbacks", default = list(), tunable = FALSE)
    ),
    par.vals = list(nrounds = 1L, verbose = 0L),
    properties = c("twoclass", "multiclass", "numerics", "prob", "weights", "missings", "featimp"),
    name = "eXtreme Gradient Boosting",
    short.name = "xgboost.c",
    note = "All settings are passed directly, rather than through `xgboost`'s `params` argument. `nrounds` has been set to `1` and `verbose` to `0` by default. `num_class` is set internally, so do not set this manually.",
    callees = "xgboost"
  )
}

#' @export
trainLearner.classif.xgboost.c = function(.learner, .task, .subset, .weights = NULL,  ...) {

  td = getTaskDesc(.task)
  parlist = list(...)
  nc = length(td$class.levels)

  if (is.null(parlist$objective))
    parlist$objective = ifelse(nc == 2L, "binary:logistic", "multi:softprob")

  if (.learner$predict.type == "prob" && parlist$objective == "multi:softmax")
    stop("objective = 'multi:softmax' does not work with predict.type = 'prob'")

  #if we use softprob or softmax as objective we have to add the number of classes 'num_class'
  if (parlist$objective %in% c("multi:softprob", "multi:softmax"))
    parlist$num_class = nc

  task.data = getTaskData(.task, .subset, target.extra = TRUE)
  label = match(as.character(task.data$target), td$class.levels) - 1
  parlist$data = xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(task.data$data), label = label)

  if (!is.null(.weights))
    xgboost::setinfo(parlist$data, "weight", .weights)

  if (is.null(parlist$watchlist))
    parlist$watchlist = list(train = parlist$data)

  do.call(xgboost::xgb.train, parlist)
}

#' @export
predictLearner.classif.xgboost.c = function(.learner, .model, .newdata, ...) {
  td = .model$task.desc
  m = .model$learner.model
  cls = td$class.levels
  nc = length(cls)
  obj = .learner$par.vals$objective

  if (is.null(obj))
    .learner$par.vals$objective = ifelse(nc == 2L, "binary:logistic", "multi:softprob")

  p = predict(m, newdata = data.matrix(.newdata), ...)

  if (nc == 2L) { #binaryclass
    if (.learner$par.vals$objective == "multi:softprob") {
      y = matrix(p, nrow = length(p) / nc, ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE)
      colnames(y) = cls
    } else {
      y = matrix(0, ncol = 2, nrow = nrow(.newdata))
      colnames(y) = cls
      y[, 1L] = 1 - p
      y[, 2L] = p
    }
    if (.learner$predict.type == "prob") {
      # VITV      
      #return(cbind(y, p))
      return(y)
    } else {
      p = colnames(y)[max.col(y)]
      names(p) = NULL
      p = factor(p, levels = colnames(y))
      return(p)
    }
  } else { #multiclass
    if (.learner$par.vals$objective  == "multi:softmax") {
      p = as.factor(p) #special handling for multi:softmax which directly predicts class levels
      levels(p) = cls
      return(p)
    } else {
      p = matrix(p, nrow = length(p) / nc, ncol = nc, byrow = TRUE)
      colnames(p) = cls
      if (.learner$predict.type == "prob") {
        return(p)
      } else {
        ind = max.col(p)
        cns = colnames(p)
        return(factor(cns[ind], levels = cns))
      }
    }
  }
}

#' @export
getFeatureImportanceLearner.classif.xgboost.c = function(.learner, .model, ...) {
  mod = getLearnerModel(.model, more.unwrap = TRUE)
  imp = xgboost::xgb.importance(feature_names = .model$features,
                                model = mod, ...)

  fiv = imp$Gain
  setNames(fiv, imp$Feature)
}
```

Here a reproducible example to demonstrate how I call the code (after having registered the methods of the new learner):

```
library(mlr)
library(dplyr)
library(titanic)

sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(titanic_train), size = floor(.7*nrow(titanic_train)), replace = F)

train <- titanic_train[sample, ] %>% select(Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Fare, Survived) %>% mutate(Sex = ifelse(Sex == 'male', 0, 1))

mlr::configureMlr(on.par.without.desc = "quiet")
lrn <- mlr::makeLearner(cl = 'classif.xgboost.c',
                        predict.type = "prob",
                        fix.factors.prediction = TRUE,
                        tree_method = 'exact',
                        early_stopping_rounds=5)

lrn <- mlr::makeImputeWrapper(lrn,
                              classes = list(integer = mlr::imputeMedian(),
                                             numeric = mlr::imputeHist(),
                                             factor = mlr::imputeMode()),
                              dummy.classes = "factor")

classif.task <- mlr::makeClassifTask(data = train,
                                     target = "Survived",
                                     positive = "1")
mod = train(lrn, classif.task)

test <- titanic_train[-sample,] %>% select(Pclass, Sex, Age, SibSp, Fare, Survived) %>% mutate(Sex = ifelse(Sex == 'male', 0, 1))

pred = predict(mod, newdata = test, predcontrib = TRUE)
calculateConfusionMatrix(pred)
```

I have the following two issues:

1. When calling the predict function with the *predcontrib* parameter
   set, this parameter is not passed into the learner predict function.
   If I check the `list(...)` I get a list of 0. Is there a way to pass the parameters into the predict function?
2. If I call the predict function *in the learner* once with a hardcoded *predcontrib* parameter set to TRUE and once without (quick and dirty trick to avoid changing the code too much at the moment)

   ```
   contrib = predict(m, newdata = data.matrix(.newdata), predcontrib = TRUE, ...)
   p = predict(m, newdata = data.matrix(.newdata), ...)
   ```

   and return both

   ```
   return(cbind(y, p))
   ```

   then I get the following error:

   ```
       Error in checkPredictLearnerOutput(.learner, .model, p) : 
     predictLearner for classif.xgboost.c.imputed has returned not the class 
   levels as column names: 0,1,p
   ```

Is there a way to change what the expected learner output is?

Comment: As this question is primarily about development, I would better be suited as an issue on [Github](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues).